# RC Design Design of foundation to resist uplift to eurocode 2 example clarification

Tags: reinforced-concrete

recently I acquired the following book
"Reinforced Concrete Design: To Eurocode 2, Book by J. H. Bungey, R. Hulse, and William Henry Mosley"

In chapter 2 example 2 the following question was posted:

**Design of a foundation to resist uplift**

Figure 2.3 shows a beam supported on foundations at A and B. The loads supported by
the beam are its own uniformly distributed permanent weight of 20 kN/m and a 170 kN
variable load concentrated at end C.

Determine the weight of foundation required at A in order to resist uplift:

(a) by applying a factor of safety of 2.0 to the reaction calculated for the working
loads.

(b) by using an ultimate limit state approach with partial factors of safety of yG (dead load) = 1.10
or 0.9 for the permanent action and yQ (imposed load) = 1.5 for the variable action. Investigate the effect on these designs of a 7 per cent increase in the variable load.

**My question is: where does the highlighted in red 8 come from?**

There is nothing in the example description or graphics to mention it.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your time.

There are two graphics[image]

Comment: 8 looks to be the full beam length (6+2)m used to multiply the 20 kN/m into units of kN.  The 2 that is then multiplied is cg distance from B.

Comment: Yes, I figured that this is probably it but it doesn't make sense. Moments are forces which act around a support. The way I thing should be calculated:
If the whole beam weights 20kN/m then the sought load at a RA must be 6x(20+RA)=2x(170+20) => RA = 43.33 kN. Not 6.7kN.

Comment: 20kN/m*(-6m*3m+2m*1m)=20kN/m*(-8m*2m).  Valid ways of calculating moments of beam weight about B should all produce the same answer.

Comment: why do you multiply on the left-hand side (-6m) by 3 if the eight is resultant based on the left side?

Comment: Just to show that if it had been two beams split at B, it would produce the same moment.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Let's say we ignore the self-weight of the beam for a second and imagine the two weights distributed around a fulcrum. If on one hand side there is a force of 170 kN at 2m away from the fulcrum then the total force exerted on 1 side will be 340 kNm. A weight which is 6m away on the other side must be at least 56.(6) kN. I don't see how the 20kN/m will reduce the result to the stated above.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the misunderstanding of this statement: "The loads supported by the beam are its **own uniform**ly distributed permanent **weight** of 20 kN/m...". It can be stated more clearly as: "The beam supports its self-weight of 20 kN/m and ...

[image]